# Can I create a new Javascript object from a nested object?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I want to create a new object from a nested object, something like this:

```
function MyObject(){
  this.myProp;
  this.myMethod = function(){};
  this.MyNestedObject = new function(){
    this.myNestedProp;
    this.myNestedMethod = function(){};
  }
}

obj = new MyObject();
myNestedObj1 = new obj.MyNestedObject;
myNestedObj2 = new obj.MyNestedObject;
myNestedObj3 = new obj.MyNestedObject;
```

I've tried several variations on this with no luck. Is there a proper syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should omit `new` in nested object. It should be simple `function`:

```
function MyObject(){
  this.myProp;
  this.myMethod = function(){};
  this.MyNestedObject = function(){  //no need of `new`
    this.myNestedProp = 5;
    this.myNestedMethod = function(){};
  }
}

obj = new MyObject();
myNestedObj1 = new obj.MyNestedObject();  //better user brackets here too
myNestedObj2 = new obj.MyNestedObject();
myNestedObj3 = new obj.MyNestedObject();
```

You will be declaring nested object (or if you prefer OOP terminology then nested class) as a simple function, which when you call with `new` acts as a constructor resolving any `this` references inside the function pointing to newly constructed object. Thus essentially when you call `**new** obj.MyNestedObject();`

> this.myNestedProp = 5;

**adds** `myNestedProp` property on newly created object (or `this` object). Similarly,

> this.myNestedMethod = function(){};

**adds** `myNestedMethod` function on newly created object (or `this` object).

If you omit `new` in

> myNestedObj1 = new obj.MyNestedObject();

Then `MyNestedObject()` will be invoked in the context of `MyObject()`. Thus `this` inside `obj.MyNestedObject()` will point to `MyObject()`. Thus before the execution of this above line, both `MyObject()` and `obj` will have three members: `myProp`, `myMethod` and `MyNestedObject`, but after execution of this call, it will add `myNestedProp` and `myNestedMethod` to the definition of `MyObject()` which in turn also appear inside `obj`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the `new` keyword, in the line:

```
  this.MyNestedObject = new function(){
```

Whenever you use the `new` keyword, you are actually instantiating a new object, and then it turns out not to be a function anymore.

Try this:

```
function MyObject(){
  this.myProp;
  this.myMethod = function(){};
  this.MyNestedObject = function(){
    this.myNestedProp;
    this.myNestedMethod = function(){};
  }
}

obj = new MyObject();
myNestedObj1 = new obj.MyNestedObject;
```